# unable to get shares_count with fql query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-fql

I'm working on a application that uses Fql and I can't seem to find a way of retrieving shares_count of a post_id, from the users stream.

If I use the post_id with the default request method like
$fb->api("/post_id") it returns all the informations of this post..including share count, while the data coming from the stream table only gives me the like and comments count.

Is there a way (maybe not yet documented ) to query the shares count of a user post.

Or, at least can I filter somehow the fields coming from $fb->api("/post_id") ? (because is to much data and I needed as minimal as possible ).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the field name of shares is, however, you *can* filter out certain fields. For example the request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/367501354973
```

...which returns a status message can be filtered to return only likes instead of all data by calling;

```
https://graph.facebook.com/367501354973?fields=likes
```

You should be able to apply `fields` to filter any request which normally returns a JSON response.

See [this documentation of the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for further reference.